# Error in dimensions of x_train and y_train

Tags: python, random-forest, shapes

I am dealing wiht a large dataset (with categorical (one hot enconding) and numerical features), and now I want to apply a random forest regressor in order to check its feature selection. This is part of my code:

```
# Split dataset in features and target variable
df1 = df

X = df1.loc[:, df1.columns != 'DI'] 

y = df1['DI'] # Target variable

X_train,y_train,X_test,y_test = train_test_split(X, y ,test_size=0.3)

rf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 100,
                           n_jobs = -1,
                           oob_score = True,
                           bootstrap = True,
                           random_state = 42)
rf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

However it shows me an error.

```
ValueError: Number of labels=2232 does not match number of samples=5207
```

I know that the shape it is different but I don't know way. Anybody can help me?

```
np.shape(X_train)
(5207, 190)

np.shape(y_train)
(2232, 190)
```

Comment: It should be `X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y ,test_size=0.3)` https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html

Comment: Yes, it was that. Thank you very much!